# How does group permissions work?

Tags: linux, permissions, process

Say `file.txt` has the following permissions:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 chris group_b 347 2016-12-25 10:19 file.txt
```

The `rw-` are the permissions for the group in which `file.txt` belongs to.

Now let's say that `Process A` wants to access `file.txt`, the `euid` of  `Process A` is `paul` (I am using names here instead of actual IDs).

Now (correct me if I'm wrong) each process has `egid` as well as a list of `supplementary group IDs`.

For example say that the `egid` for `Process A` is `group_a` and it has two `supplementary group IDs`, which are `group_b` and `group_c`.

This means that the process group permissions for `file.txt` (`rw-`) applies to `Process A`, correct?

Also, if `Process A` created a new file or a new directory, which group will the newly created file or directory belongs to (`Process A` has 3 groups), is it the `egid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This means that the process group permissions for file.txt (rw-) applies to Process A, correct?

Yes, correct.

> Also, if Process A created a new file or a new directory, which group will the newly created file or directory belongs to (Process A has 3 groups), is it the egid?

Assuming that the directory the new file/directory is created into does not have its setgid bit set, yes.

If you want `Process A` to create its new files and directories with group `group_b` instead of the default `group_a`, you could start `Process A` with command `sg group_b Process_A`.

Or if a particular directory was designated for collaboration for `group_c`, then the owner of that directory could have set the group for that directory to `group_c` and then set the setgid bit for that directory:

```
mkdir /some/directory
chgrp group_c /some/directory
chmod g+rwxs /some/directory
```

Now, any new files and sub-directories created in that directory will automatically get their group ownership set to `group_c`. Any new sub-directories will inherit both the group ownership and the setgid bit, so this behavior will automatically propagate to any sub-directories and sub-sub-directories and so on as soon as they are created, unless the creator explicitly changes the group ownership or permissions.